# A way to handle write operations (600k records) to cosmos db using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have a .Net Core 3.1 application. I'm trying to create an implementation that will handle ~600k writes to Cosmos database and the same amount of deletion operations. It takes a lot of time to execute the SaveChangesAsync method. Cosmos database has auto-scaling enabled with max RU/s set to 1k.

Setting AutoDetectChangesEnabled to false didn't help. Should I divide the number of operations and for each group trigger SaveChanges?

Can someone help me out finding the best way to handle high volume write operation to cosmos db using entity framework (3.1.23 version)?

Here is the code example (I renamed some values/methods):

```
                _context.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
                var pohs = _context.A
                    .Where(x => x.Num == num)
                    .ToList();
                var pols = _context.B.ToList();
                var removed = from x in pols
                                    join y in pohs
                                    on x.Id equals y.id
                                    select x;

                _context.B.RemoveRange(removed.ToList());
                _context.A.RemoveRange(pohs);

                var anotherheaders = CreateXXX(temp.GetXXX(num));
                _context.A.AddRange(anotherheaders);             
_context.B.AddRange(tempLines.GetXXX(purchaseOrderHeaders));

                _context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

**UPDATE:**
Elements in the AddRange and RemoveRange have different partitions. I saw that requests made to Cosmos db reached the max ru/s limit. However, after I increased it to 10k it didn't really speed up the process.

Comment: You should take a look at the average RU cost for each of your operations, to help you decide how much RU/sec you need to allocate in your collection. Also consider that these RU/sec get split across physical partitions (you haven't shared anything about data quantity, but it's something to think about). Not sure there's anything specific to your code, regarding performance (aside from maybe parallel operations.

Comment: May be you need to include what you what to achieve maybe cosmos db is not the right approach

Comment: @MaythamFahmi - not sure how you can just rule out a particular database engine because of a scale question. Unless there's some unsupported operation the OP needs, that doesn't really seem to apply.

Comment: One more question about the issue you're having: What does "takes a lot of time" mean? How many operations/second are you seeing? Are you receiving 429's (throttling, meaning you've exhausted your RU allocation for a given 1-second window)? These details are important.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, I stopped the application after waiting for like 20 minutes, and I didn't get any exception. Is there a way to check how many RU/s each EF write costs?

Comment: I'm planning to divide the data into smaller chunks and process it parallelly. Each partition has a unique value so I wouldn't expect conflicts.

Comment: @dawids8 also enable Bulk when you create the client and also disableWriteBack on upsert, should be no issue at all to write 100s if not 1000s of documents / second

Comment: @MattDouhan, does the fact that in the addRange (or RemoveRange) I have items from different partitions might cause a performance issue?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I don't think an object-database mapper like EF is the right tool to do bulk write operations. I suggest looking for alternative means.

Comment: @dawids8 not really but can you show the code where you create the client

Comment: @MattDouhan, I'm not using a client. I'm initializing a db context with EF configuration.  The Cosmos SDK NuGet package was recently updated with the option to allow bulk operations. I tested it and it was at least 10 times faster. I think there is an EF limitation with storing a huge amount of data - it is writing/removing like 20-60 records per sec no matter how many RU/s limit I set for cosmos db.

Comment: @dawids8 hmm ok I am not an EF expert but it sounds weird it would have such a limitation,

Comment: We've decided to use Cosmos SDK instead of EF at the project. The performance with the bulk option enabled for cosmos clients is significantly better. Once an azure web job started processing a huge collection of data it was super fast. It's throwing a cosmos exception now because of too many requests, many of them are throttled. I'll manipulate RU/s limit and partition values to prevent that. Anyway - thanks all for the help!